# Replacing momentary button/switch on monitor control panel

Tags: switches, components, wiring, replacement

There is a button that toggle inputs on my monitor and the very thin top dome/bubble came off and not I can't really press it to work, though if I use a flat head screwdriver (the diameter of the metallic circle in the button), I can make it work but it's a real PITA to do it a few times a day.  I couldn't fine any of these exact buttons but I have similar ones from another monitor that are just slightly different and I think the size/spacing is close enough to work but IDK how to test if this is the right kind of button or if it wil work at all.

I'm worried about fit, b/c it might be off 7-10 thousandth's in one direction and 3-5 in the other, but they are pretty darn close.  I could always use some very fine wire and connect the button off the board b/c the monitors have been de-bezeled & on a custom mount so the boards are attached to the side of the mounting.

The biggest issue is connecting the lead the way they are needed and IDK how to test a button/switch like this.  Here's a pic of the two boards and I labeled them as best I could. I showed where I touch the broken switch to get it to work and the line is the relative size of the flat head or angled tweezers I use.

[image: monitor control boards]

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to be sure, but it looks like the bottom board contains complete tactile switches, while the top one has dome switches.  The dome switches work by having the dome in contact with the outer pads and making contact to a center pad when pressed.  Tactile switches work by connecting (usually) two of the four leads to the other two (the main reason for having four leads is mounting stability).  They won't work as a direct replacement.  However, if you solder wires to the outer and center contacts on the top board, those could be attached to a tactile switch and would work, although mounting it mechanically will be a craft project.